# How to storage the outputs of an iterable function

Tags: python, pandas, function

Probably this is very simple, but I can not figure it out how is the proper way to produce a dataframe in pandas, with the outputs of my function.

Let's say that I have a function that divide each element of a list (let's omitting the easiest way to divide a list):

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in X:
    def SUM(X):
        output = i / 2
        return output

df = SUM(X)
```

At the end 'df' represent the last operation performed by my function. But how can I append all the outputs in a Dataframe?
Thanks by your suggestions

Comment: Why are you having a function inside the `for` loop. and why are you not using it at all inside loop. and looks completely wrong for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create DataFrame in first step and then processing column values by [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)?

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def SUM(X):
    output = X / 2
    return output

df = pd.DataFrame({'in':X})
df['out'] = df['in'].apply(SUM)
print (df)
   in  out
0   1  0.5
1   2  1.0
2   3  1.5
3   4  2.0
4   5  2.5
5   6  3.0
```

Your solution should be used:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

def SUM(X):
    output = X / 2
    return output

out = [SUM(i) for i in X]

df = pd.DataFrame({'out':out})
print (df)
   out
0  0.5
1  1.0
2  1.5
3  2.0
4  2.5
5  3.0
```